# Regex: Comma delimited integers

Tags: regex, csv

I'm trying to create a regex that accept:
An empty string, a single integer or multiple integers separated by a comma but can have no starting and ending comma.

I managed to find this, but I cannot undertsand how to remove the digit limit

```
^\d{1,10}([,]\d{10})*$
```

Comment: Note that `[,]` is equivalent to `,` and you probably meant to write `([,]\d{1,10})*` instead of `([,]\d{10})*`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The thing you posted still requires at least 1 integer, so it won't match an empty string:

Here is what you need:

```
^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$
```

Explaination:

1. put the entire thing in parenthesis and end with a **`'?'`** so as to match the empty string.
2. Always start with an integer, so **`'\d+'.`**  That is 1 or more digit characters **`('0'-'9')`**
3. Then make a set of parenthesis which contains **`',\d+'`** and put an asterisk after it.
   3a. The inside means start with a ',' then an integer.
   3b. The asterisk means repeat everything inside the parenthesis 0 or more times.

Hench the whole thing is `either an empty string or start with an integer then repeat zero or more times a string which starts with a comma and ends with an integer`

Answer (score 3):

`{1,10}` and `{10}` are ranges. You can replace them with `+` for infinite-positive. Eg.:

```
^\d+([,]\d+)*$
```

Comment: Methinks that you can also omit the square brackets around the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers hit on 4 digits between commas. Here is a slight variation with an optional sign and enforcing 3 digits between commas:

```
^[+-]?(\d+(,\d{3})*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extend tster's answer by making the inner group a non capturing group.

```
^(\d+(?:,\d+)*)?$
```

Consider for example

```
re.search('^(\d+(?:,\d+)*)?$', "1,2,3,4").groups() 
('1,2,3,4',)
```

which returns a tuple of 1 element. But if the inner group is a capturing group, you get one extra element at the end.

```
re.search('^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$', "1,2,3,4").groups()
('1,2,3,4', ',4')
```