# How to write regex to verify a comma delimited list of integers of unknown size?

Tags: regex, csv, integer

```
308091,1213,13414,12132,14431,14343,234,4334,2,34234,2344,32424
```

should match, preferably if I could verify also that there was NO trailing comma that would be grand... not sure how I would write this or if it would even be possible... letters should fail, any symbols besides numbers and commas should fail, any number of integers should be possible from one '12345' or two '12345,12345' and on to infinity '12345,98765,...'

good luck

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: Comma delimited integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921453/regex-comma-delimited-integers)

Comment: @Martin What happened to your answer? It had a good thread of informative comments. If I had chosen yours as the answer, I wonder if you would have still deleted your answer and flagged to close this question. Good form.

Comment: You should consider assuming good faith :) I deleted my answer because it added no value after Ikke's solution was posted. Right then I happened to spot an identical question in the list to the right and proceeded to mark this question as a duplicate since it has already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only numbers (so 0123 wouldn't work) then you could use this pattern:

```
^([1-9][0-9]*,)*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Comment: perfect, fits the bill because an integer cannot start with zero, tested and confirmed

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*$
```