# Regex for non empty CSV string of positive integers

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to check if a string matches a *non empty CSV pattern with positive integers*, e.g `34,657547,453,346654` but also single integers like `2` or `3943`.

I tried `^\d+(,\d+)*$` as the regex (as described in [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921453/regex-comma-delimited-integers) and removing the part which allows an empty string), but if I try this on https://regex101.com/ with my example input of `34,657547,453,346654` it tells me that the only match would be `,346654`. If I try `34` it says no matches

For my understanding:

```
^ // Start of String
\d+ // A digit, at least one time
( ...) // Grouping for the next
,\d+ // a comma and at least one digit
* // Repeating the grouping zero to unlimited times
$ // End of String
```

So my too questions:

1. So what do I have to change, that I get what I need?
2. Is there a way to don't allow zero as a single entry too? So `34,0,354` or `0` would be invalid. I thought about using `[1-9]` instead of `\d` in my regex but this would strike out numbers like `10, 1034`.

In the end I'm thinking of a script including a function like this:

```
function validateCSV($string) {
  $regEx = "^\d+(,\d+)*$";

  // Don't know if this preg_match syntax is right.
  // Didn't wrote the script yet because of the failure (?) of my regex in onlinetool
  return (preg_match($regEx, $string) > 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: You're misinterpreting the output of regex101. It matches the whole string but it **captures** only the last number - the last number matched by `(,\d+)`. It's put inside `()` to do the repeat, but that also means it's a capture group. You can make it a non capturing group by starting it with `?:` - `^\d+(?:,\d+)*$` but in your case that's not necessary. You're good as it is.

Comment: @ClasG I accepted Marianos answer but I'd like to thank you for the explanation about the (non) capturing group! So i voted at least your comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ClasG pointed out in the comment, your regex is working. It is indeed matching the whole line, and only capturing the las token matched. The group `(,\d+)*` is overwritten on repetition.

In order to exclude matching `0` tokens, you can use the following expression:

```
/^0*[1-9]\d*(?:,0*[1-9]\d*)*$/
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB1cA2/2)</kbd>

---

As you can see, for each number, it matches:

```
0*          # any number of leading zeros
[1-9]       # requires 1 digit different than 0
\d*         # any number of digits
```

---

One more thing, you're checking if `preg_match($regEx, $string) > 1`. However, `preg_match` only returns `1` if matched or `0` otherwise in this case (we're not using an offset). You could symply return the value:

```
return preg_match($regEx, $string);
```

Comment: So if I change your regex to `^[1-9]\d*(?:,[1-9]\d*)*$` than leading zeros (like `034`) are also not allowed right? Or do I missinterpreting regex101 wrong again?